# How to: Compare dictionaries within lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I was wondering if you could help me.

I have two lists that contain dictionaries, for the most part these keys are the same. See below for a brief example:

```
x1 = [{'a':1,'b':"cat"},{'a':2,'b':"parrot"},...]
x2 = [{'a':2,'b':"dog"},{'a':1,'b':"fish"},...]
```

Now I would like to compare the values based on a key i.e. key a, But the length of both lists will not always be the same. The key a will always be in both dictionaries if there is a corresponding dictionary i.e. `x1[0]['a'] == x2[1]['a']`.

How could I compare these dictionaries based on key a so that I could firstly discard those from `x1` that do not appear in `x2`, vise versa. Then determine if certain values appear in both dictionaries and then record this in a database, this is not necessary here.

What I was thinking was to combine these dictionaries into a tuple within a list based on key a. Then iterate through this and compare these values. This is probably not the best  way to go about it, so if you have better ideas, please feel free. :)

[Edit.]

I didn't phrase the question clearly, I'm sorry. What I'm hoping to do is; first: match dictionaries based on key a. Second: Ignore those that do not match(key a). Third: Compare key b. fourth: update the database based on the comparison of b.

Thank you to all those who have answered.

My answer would be something like this:

"I thought a list comp might do fine to build a tuple containing a dictionary from `x1` that corresponds with the dictionary from `x2`, then iterate through each tuple comparing key b but I thought it might be too slow."

I don't think it's a very good way of doing it. So that's why I'm here :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please describe your wanted outcome.  Comparing all pairs is easy but what shall be done with the results of all those comparisons?

Comment: And what shall happen if the lists aren't equally long (as you state can happen)?

Comment: Can you please explain the statement? `The key a will always be in both dictionaries if there is a corresponding dictionary `. Your example is not quite helpful.

Comment: @Abhijit meaning that a corresponding dictionary will not always exist, i.e. x1[n]['a'] might = 57 and there is no matching dictionary for x2, so ignore x1[n]. Does this help?

Comment: So you want to iterate `x1` and for each a-value found therein you want to _search_ that a-value in `x2`?  Or shall only pairs be compared which have the same position in `x1` and `x2`?

Comment: @Alfe Yes to the former, I need to know how to search through x1 to find the corresponding dictionary in x2 based on key a. Which I then compare key b of both. I thought a list comp might do fine to build a tuple containing a dictionary from x1 that corresponds with the dictionary from x2, then iterate through each tuple comparing key b but I thought it might be too slow.

Comment: Okay, now the question is interesting ;-)

Comment: So is the answer I have given similar to the one you considered but decided would be too slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly what you want is something like this, which works by turning the two lists into dictionaries with the 'a' values as keys. It assumes there is no replication of the 'a' values within each list and returns a dictionary with the 'a' values as keys and the tuples of the paired 'b's as values.

```
x1 = [{'a':1,'b':"cat"}, {'a':2,'b':"parrot"}, {'a': 3, 'b': 'dog'}]
x2 = [{'a':2,'b':"dog"}, {'a':1,'b':"fish"}]
x1_d = {d['a']: d['b'] for d in x1}
x2_d = {d['a']: d['b'] for d in x2}
matched_keys = set(x1_d) & set(x2_d)
result = {key: (x1_d[key], x2_d[key]) for key in matched_keys}
print result     # {1: ('cat', 'fish'), 2: ('parrot', 'dog')}
```

There may be quicker ways of doing this but maybe you could confirm if this is the kind of result you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get your comparison, but I guess what you want is

```
len(x1)==len(x2) and all(a['a']==b['a'] for (a, b) in zip(x1, x2))
```

or, equivalently (but less efficient),

```
[a['a'] for a in x1] == [b['a'] for b in x2]
```

Comment: It's kind of implied that not all `dict`s will contain key `a`, but will do so if one of them does... so there's a potential exception on the second....

Comment: @JonClements I see. We can use `[a.get('a') for a in x1] == [b.get('a') for b in x2]` instead. If a `dict` doesn't contain key `a`, we get two `None`s in both lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you just call

```
[ a['a'] == b['a'] for a, b in zip(x1, x2) ]
```

you will get a list of comparison results.  In case the lists aren't equally long, the shorter will determine how many pairs there are compared.

Notice that the result will be a list of boolean values (`True`, `False`).  If you want anything else, please specify this more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

```
x1 = [{'a':1,'b':"cat"},{'a':2,'b':"parrot"}]
x2 = [{'a':2,'b':"dog"},{'a':1,'b':"fish"},{'a':3},{'a':2}]

[(_x2,_x2['a'] in [_x1['a'] for _x1 in x1]) for _x2 in x2]
[({'a': 2, 'b': 'dog'}, True),
 ({'a': 1, 'b': 'fish'}, True),
 ({'a': 3}, False),
 ({'a': 2}, True)]
```

This code works in one direction. You can adapt it to both directions, or just use it twice.